# How are these 2 lines of PHP different?

Tags: php, hash, hmac

Assuming we have a salt that's in the database and that has been generated like this

`$salt = time();`

What is the difference between these 2 lines.

```
$pass1 = hash('sha1', $password . $salt);

$pass2 = hash_hmac('sha1', $password, $salt);
```

They don't produce the same output. The first one, the `hash` function takes 2 params, while the `hash_hmac` needs 3 params. You would therefore think that we can get that third extra param by using the `$salt` separately (to fulfill the third param) as opposed to concatenating it with the password (`$password . $salt`) like we did in line 2. But it's not that simple, the 2 results are different. Why? What is going on exactly here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because HMAC SHA-1 is not the same as SHA-1 with the message and key concatenated. HMAC is more like `sha1($salt . sha1($salt . $password))`, but not exactly. Wikipedia has a nice description of [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Comment: I see. So when using HMAC, do you still need to worry about generating separate random salts for each record to store in the database? or do you only give HMAC a standard string e.g. `hash_hmac('sha1', $pass, "standard");` and no random salt is needed?

Comment: random salt will be needed anyways to protect against rainbow tables.

Comment: Thanks Lukas and Etan. Cleared up now.