# Hash in Java with or without salt

Tags: java, encryption, salt

I'm trying to make a method for encoding to SHA(128,256,512) with or without salt. The method for no salt is

```
private static String crypt(String chain, String method) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(method);
        md.update(chain.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] mb = md.digest();
        String out = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < mb.length; i++) {
            byte temp = mb[i];
            String s = Integer.toHexString(new Byte(temp));
            while (s.length() < 2) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }
            s = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
            out += s;
        }
        return out;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

where the method can be

```
private final static String MD5="MD5";
private final static String SHA_128="SHA-1";
private final static String SHA_256="SHA-256";
private final static String SHA_384="SHA-384";
```

but I'd like also to have a method crypt(String chain,String salt, String method). I tried changing the line to:

```
byte[] mb=md.digest(salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

But it doesn't return the correct chain (compared with the php call **hash_hmac('sha256','pass','salt')**). How can I fix that or where can I find a method with optional salt for those algorithms? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How are these 2 lines of PHP different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629415/how-are-these-2-lines-of-php-different) for the difference between HMAC and just concatenating with salt.